# Error - messages howto

Tags: coding-style

I have question, maybe it's not critical in programming, but to me it's very interesting.
I am writing a parser, and now, when he grew up in code somewhere it's very important embed some kind of warning. I mean, I have a class loader, and if you did not specify path to the texture, parser class send message it to console, that path is not specified, but the rest of it is loaded. Actually what I want to ask - is there any system of classification system messages, and where can i read about it.

I mean the qualification system messages such as:

- NOTICE: olololo - the application will be to work fine, but you should pay attention to this message
- ATENTION: olololo - an error which may entail the failure of the program
- WARNING: olololo - there was a problem in which future work program, in any case lead to an error, so the application will be closed forcibly.

i'll be glad to any advice, if from personal experience is even better))) and yes, I'm just learning to programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "how do I categorize my logging messages by severity level", this is an example of what levels the [standard Java logging library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html)uses:

```
SEVERE (highest value)
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
FINE
FINER
FINEST (lowest value)
```

Alternatively, [sl4j](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/apache/log4j/Level.html)

```
FATAL: designates very severe error events that will presumably lead the application to abort.
ERROR: designates error events that might still allow the application to continue running.
WARN: designates potentially harmful situations.
INFO: designates informational messages that highlight the progress of the application at coarse-grained level.
DEBUG: designates fine-grained informational events that are most useful to debug an application.
TRACE: designates finer-grained informational events than the DEBUG
```